# Process hash fragment using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment-identifier

i want to get hash parameters value in my java script
for example my url should be like that

```
www.example.com/#!mydata=data&myopt=option
```

i want to get mydata in variable which will be "data" as value,
and myopt "option"

iam trying to implement google ajax cowling like here
[Google Code](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/)

and i have tried to implement [jquery address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

but with big fail so help me either by solving 1st part or give me simple walk through tutorial to implement jquery address to my ajax requests ,thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code will convert any well formed (i.e. properly url-encoded) request string into an object literal with values parsed.

```
var s = "#!mydata=data&myopt=option";
var o = {};

$.each(s.substr(2).split('&'), function(i, elem) {
   var parts = elem.split('=');
   o[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});
```

Then you can access values like `o.myopt`

**UPDATE**

Of course, to get the value from browser's address, you should use

```
var s = window.location.hash;
```